# Jersey 1.13 web service on Weblogic 12.2.1.x

Tags: jersey, weblogic, weblogic12c, jersey-1.0

I am trying to get a very simple Jersey web service to run on Weblogic 12.2.1.x but I am failing miserably

In my `web.xml` I have the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>jersey1test</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.jersey1test</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/srv/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And the webservice resource itself is very simple

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("jersey1test")
public class Jersey1Resource
{

    @Path("hello")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response helloJersey()
    {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("Hello from Jersey 1").build();
    }

}
```

And I have exclusively jersey 1.13 dependecies in my pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And as suggested on this [oracle page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/version.htm) I have the following in my weblogic.xml deployed with my war

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <!— jersey-bundle-*.jar->
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</package-name>

        <!— Jackson-*.jar ->
        <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.jackson.*</wls:package-name>

        <!— jettison-*.jar ->
        <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.jettison.*</wls:package-name>

        <!— jsr311*.jar ->
        <wls:package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</wls:package-name>

        <!— asm.jar ->
        <wls:package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

The war deploys fine but when trying to access the webservice I just receive a not found response (the same URI btw works when this is deployed to weblogic 12.1.3 or Glassfish 3/4)

One thing I have noticed is I see the following in the server logs (I can't see any exceptions)

```
<15-Jul-2016 08:39:55 o'clock BST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192509> <Changing servlet class from com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer (web.xml) to org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.> 
<15-Jul-2016 08:39:55 o'clock BST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
<15-Jul-2016 08:39:55 o'clock BST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.ApplicationAdapter because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
<15-Jul-2016 08:39:55 o'clock BST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
<15-Jul-2016 08:39:55 o'clock BST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClassNamesResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
<15-Jul-2016 08:39:55 o'clock BST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.DefaultResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
<15-Jul-2016 08:39:55 o'clock BST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
<15-Jul-2016 08:39:55 o'clock BST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
<15-Jul-2016 08:39:55 o'clock BST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
<15-Jul-2016 08:39:55 o'clock BST> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.>
```

Which to me seems to suggest it's ignoring what I've set in my `weblogic.xml`. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to have a jersey 1 web service working in weblogic 12.2.1.x?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is a compatibility issue with 12.2.1.x.

You have the option of downgrading your version of WebLogic, or upgrading to Jersey 2 (why aren't you using Jersey 2 by the way?)

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3923266?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Yes I saw that post I wasn't sure if it was an official not supported statement or not. As for why Jersey 1, it's a web service developed a few years ago, the above is just a simple example which would give the same issue as the real one.